# How to slow down first program in pipe until second program is ready

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I have a script running as so:

```
cat in | prog1 2>log1 | prog2 2>log2 | prog3 2>log3 > out
```

`<in>` can have millions of lines and I want each program to only produce output on `STDOUT` when the next program's `STDIN` has been consumed.

This is because `prog1` uses system resources that `prog2` cleans up once it's done with it.

So basically I want `cat` to "pause" between line writes until said lines have been consumed by `prog1`, and onward down the line.

I have tried using `stdbuf` but that doesn't appear to have any effect, i.e.:

```
stdbuf -o0 cat in | stdbuf -o0 -i0 prog1 2>log1 | stdbuf -o0 -i0 prog2 2>log2 | stdbuf -o0 i0 prog3 2>log3 > out
```

Using `pv -l` between each pipe confirms the speed difference, and also `tail -f` of the different log files.

Is there a way to do this?

I am aware that this will adversely affect performance.

PS I also want the whole pipe to exit when any of the programs exit, and each of the programs are legacy written in either perl or python, so they can't just be combined.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at `sponge` (soak up standard input and write to a file or stdout).

Comment: When a pipe's buffer is full, writes to the pipe block until data is read. In other words, it already works like you want

Comment: thank you but what you describe with `sponge` is precisely the opposite of what I want to achieve, perhaps I need to rephrase the question.

Comment: @DukeLeto: I probably misunderstood you.

Comment: Slowing down `cat in` won't help much if `prog1` buffers output because then it might still outrun `prog2` for a while.

Comment: @melpomene yes I want to slow all the programs such that new STDOUT lines are only produced when the next program's STDIN is empty. thanks!

Comment: what you describe above **is** the way piping data should work. But you also state "This is because prog1 uses system resources that prog2 cleans up once ..." which is some really advanced programming (using shared memory?, but inside `perl`?) So `prog[12]` seem to not be designed to work with pipes, which does happen. I would use temp files as mentioned below. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you insist on using pipes? The whole point of piping data is "First In, First Out". If you want regimented processes, use temporary files.

```
prog1 < in 2>log1 > $(mktemp)
prog2 < $_ 2>log2 > $(mktemp)
# etc...
```

edit: In this context, `$_` means "the last argument of the last command line".